# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm x25519 not available

Tags: java, jlink, java-14

I am getting a "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset" for this piece of code

```
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(url.getInputStream());
```

but only when running under a Java 14 JRE built with jlink from  Open JDK 14. The code executes just fine if I point to the full JDK. I suspect something is missing in the JRE, but what is it and why did jlink not copy the missing files accross? My jlink command based on jdeps is as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14\bin\jlink.exe" --no-header-files --no-man-pages --compress=2 --strip-debug --add-modules java.base,java.datatransfer,java.desktop,java.logging,java.xml --output %AG14InstallDir%\jre_windows2
```

Am I missing a module in the jlink? Any ideas or suggestion on how to track this down?

After adding the debug as suggested, I get this output. What do I need to copy across to fix it?

```
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|2E|Thread-13|2020-06-07 10:22:24.517 UTC|null:-1|Signature algorithm, ed25519, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|2E|Thread-13|2020-06-07 10:22:24.518 UTC|null:-1|Signature algorithm, ed448, is not supported by the underlying providers
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|2E|Thread-13|2020-06-07 10:22:24.519 UTC|null:-1|No AlgorithmParameters for x25519 (
"throwable" : {
  java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm x25519 not available
    at java.base/javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.NamedGroup.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.NamedGroup.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SignatureScheme.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    .............
```

Comment: Have you run with `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to see if there is anything in the traces? It may be that you need a crypto provider that is not in the java.base module, e.g. jdk.crypto.ec.

Answer (score 12):

Solved. Need to add jdk.crypto.cryptoki to the --add-modules list in jlink.

Comment: While this works, apparently it is working because jdk.crypto.cryptoki has a dependency on jdk.crypto.ec which is what is actually missing. So if you --add-module jdk.crypto.ec it fixes this issue as well. cryptoki add support for a SUN PKCS11, which I didn't need.

Comment: Was getting the same error in Java 16 while trying to download the djl.ai deep learning libraries using a bespoke JRE.  jdk.crypto.ec was the missing module.  Note that it doesn't show up when using the jdeps command